# How to adjust brightness on Android TV?

Tags: android-tv, screen-brightness

I have a TCL U55P6046 (EU version of the TCL 55P607). The EU version comes with Android TV instead of Roku TV.

I am trying to change the brightness on this TV, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I did find the backlight, but changing it does not seem to help.

I have the latest Android TV version available for me which is 6.x.

How to adjust brightness on Android TV?

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Frequent settings > All settings > Picture [settings] > Brightness

At least my Android TV has this path.

Comment: Thanks the answer :-) It might be vendor specific. Do you know which Android version does it have?

Answer (score 0):

in TCL Android Pie TV

Settings > Picture > Brightness